# How do I decrypt my own iMessage SSL Application Data in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption

I was capturing my own packets from my iPhone 4 when I was using iMessage, with WireShark, for my Computer Networks class, and I was wondering, given the encrypted data below, how could I decrypt the message so I could see the message that I sent?

Frame:
https://gist.github.com/1748447

Data:
https://gist.github.com/1748444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the jumble of text you've linked to for the data part of the iMessage, it's highly unlikely that anyone is going to decrypt this unless you had insider information. Apple should be using strong encryption algorithms (such as AES) for its iMessage protocol. I'd bet that if you sent the exact same iMessage to the exact same destination, you're going to get different encrypted data. You could imagine the privacy issues that would arise if people could easily discern an encrypted 'yes' message vs. a 'no' message.

Furthermore, these encryption algorithms base their security on mathematical problems (eg. discrete logarithm problems, prime factorization) which are very hard to compute.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [interesting study of Apple's iMessage](http://blog.quarkslab.com/imessage-privacy.html) protocol which shows that whilst it is encrypted end-to-end, it's not secure against Apple snooping on it as Apple runs the key distribution system.

Basically iMessages are encrypted using an AES key and signed using the sender ECDSA key so you're not going to decrypt an message without doing a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://github.com/meeee/pushproxy) to extract the keys, or possibly [dumping the keys](https://github.com/reinitialized/Keychain-Dumper) from the key store on the actual device that's sending the messages. But this has [gotten harder as iOS/OSX](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56749/is-apples-push-notification-service-implementation-vulnerable-to-a-mitm-attack) has evolved.

Comment: While Apple does store-and-forward some messages the they have no administration access to the HSMs (Hardware Security Modules) that contain the keys because they shred the smart card keys to the HSM's after setup. Note: The post pointed to was written prior to Apple destroying the HSM admin keys so is no longer accurate..

Comment: The use of an 'HSM' (Apple don't use a real one - they use their 'secure enclave'/ARMTrustZone) doesn't stop Apple from performing a MiTM on each user as detailed in section 4.4 of the study since all iMessages pass through the Apple Push Notification Service (APNs). Anyway the question was about iOS 5 which predates Apple's 'Secure Enclave'.

Comment: Apple has lot's of "real" HSMs and iMessage does use them, I suggest you start by reading Apple's security disclosure concerning iMessage. I am not talking about the 'secure enclave' in iPhone6' which is not an HSM and is only used for payments at least currently.

Comment: So how do these HSMs stop Apple from performing a MiTM attack on any iMessage user? Apple stores the public keys for all users and could instead provide a 'surveillance' key for any user if they wished and do the same for recipient.

Comment: Start with [iOS Security
October 2014](https://www.apple.com/br/privacy/docs/iOS_Security_Guide_Oct_2014.pdf). From page 36: "These policies are coded in the HSM firmware. The administrative access cards that permit the firmware to be changed have been destroyed."

Comment: That is only relevant to keychain escrow would only change whether Apple could get to your private keys, but it's independent of the fact that Apple controls which keys are provided to encrypt iMessages - when an iMessage recipient is selected their key is obtained from Apple's servers so Apple could insert their own key and then re-encrypt the message with the bogus ID to the recipient - There is no way to independently verify that whether a key belongs to a certain user. Just like with PGP - you have to do out of bound key exchange to be sure there's no MiTM.

Comment: Furthermore there are two more issues with cloud based HSMs - A) One only has Apple's word that they're in the cloud - there's no way to verify that they're there or being used. B) How can one be sure that you're actually talking to Apple's cloud as opposed to an Intelligence Agency cloud that's pretending to be Apple (Given they've probably acquired, or have access to, enough top US based CA keys)?

Comment: The original article I linked on iMessage MiTM in my answer has recently been quoted by security expert Nick Weaver on the Lawfare blog confirming my position on Apple being capable of reading iMessages: https://www.lawfareblog.com/iphones-fbi-and-going-dark

Comment: Oh, *tinfoil-hat* time: "HSMs - there's no way to verify that they're there or being used." Nick Weaver quote from the linked article: "Properly configured, an iOS device is perhaps the most secure, general purpose communication device available." and "I still like iPhones, I still use and recommend iPhones, and iMessage remains perhaps the best usable covert communication channel available today if your adversary can’t compromise Apple."

Comment: Ultimately, if the person is of national security interest most bets are off as there is always [Rubber-hose cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis) that can be brought to bear.

Comment: Sure. But the original comment was raised saying Apple can't read the messages but they can if they want. By the way Nick's article was also linked in Bruce Schneier's  CRYPTO-GRAM (15 Aug 15).

Comment: You say that can , Apple says they can't. You posit that they may not have HSMs, that they may not be being used, that is just crazy talk. It would seem that it is in Apple's best interest to not be able to read the message, that frees them form having to fulfill large numbers of requests, they just reply: "We Can't". So: Who to believe, Apple or crazy talk? P.S. I read the CRYPTO-GRAM too, Bruce links to lots of things, probably 100+ per issue, that does not make them true.

Comment: It's not only me saying it - I seriously doubt Bruce Schneier would link to dodgy security analysis - having authored 12 Books on security, fellow at Harvard Law School etc. And Nick Weaver, Lawfare are also very unlikely to make such a mistake. Anyway it's clear from their security design that a MiTM attack by Apple is possible - HSMs are a red herring.

Comment: From the current (August 15, 2015) CRYPTO-GRAM (emphasis mine): "There's a persistent rumor going around that Apple is in the secret FISA Court, fighting a government order to make its platform more surveillance-friendly -- and they're losing. This might explain Apple CEO Tim Cook's somewhat sudden vehemence about privacy. **I have not found any confirmation of the rumor**."

Comment: As for what Apple could do, the answer is much because they create the code and devices. That does not mean by any stretch of the imagination that they do, would want to or are dishonest about what they are doing. Using the "could do" argument one could just as easily state that any of the 40+ million in the U.S. who own a handgun could kill someone. Could is not a good metric.

Comment: Just to add that Prof. Matthew Green has also blogged on the issue http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/06/can-apple-read-your-imessages.html - the article maybe from 2013 but it is still applicable as referenced from his latest published attack on iMessage this year http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/03/attack-of-week-apple-imessage.html

Comment: From the 2016 blog: "The results of this analysis include some very neat new attacks that allow us to -- **under very specific circumstances** -- decrypt the contents of iMessage attachments, such as photos and videos." and a MITM even given Certificate Pinning. Also this attack does not work with  iOS 9.3 and Mac OS X 10.11.4 and above. Further from the comments: "It appears that the phone would receive very many garbled messages/attachments/pictures from an unknown sender." where very many is thousands.

Comment: I was referring to the first article which explains the point we were debating regarding **Apple reading your iMessages**. I only mentioned his latest article just to indicate the relevance of the first one - His second article is about a separate design flaw in iMessage which potentially allowed **anyone** to decrypt attachments.

Comment: Keep soldiering on about what the evil Apple could do.

Comment: I'm not anti-Apple but their current design of iMessages does permit them to set things up so they could read your iMessages (not previous iMessages) - however given their stance against the FBI I think it's probably happened extremely rarely - if at all. It is better people understand that systems are flawed in certain ways - most real systems are.

Comment: It is disingenuous to imply that Apple would read your iMessages and also state you are not anti-Apple which I did not state. If Apple is not to be trusted then iOS which they write can not be trusted, the OS where the messages are created. Apple already has access to all iMessages at creation time! So saying **Apple reading your iMessages** is a mute point. Understanding the systems is indeed a good thing.